# ripple effect not working when add onTouchListener() to a view

Tags: android, android-layout

Ripple effect working fine when using onClick listener on view but not working when we perform onTouch listener on view

Comment: Please add more details and what have you done so far.

Answer (score 2):

try using

**`return false;`**

in your `onTouch` method.

Comment: by returning false listener  will perform same action twice